# Grab the title attribute of each <a> tag and then append it in the containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive my newbiness, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I am trying to make a YouTube gallery using fancybox for a friend. It will have several items following this layout:

```
<a href="youtubevideo1" class="fancybox" title="title1">
    <img src="imggoeshere" />
</a>
<a href="youtubevideo2" class="fancybox" title="title2">
    <img src="imggoeshere" />
</a>
<a href="youtubevideo3" class="fancybox" title="title3">
    <img src="imggoeshere" />
</a>
<a href="youtubevideo4" class="fancybox" title="title4">
    <img src="imggoeshere" />
</a>
```

What I want to do is use jquery to go through each `<a>` tag, retrieve the title, and then print it into something like this:

```
<div class="title">titlegoeshere</div>
```

after each `<a>` tag is closed.

I've tried to modify a bunch of different snippets that I've found online but am striking out.

Comment: Post your `html` where exactly is `div.title`, or is it for every `a`?

Comment: Show us what you currently have for jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jmv344en/

That's the jsfiddle I'm trying to work with

Comment: What you mean by _after each <a> tag is closed._?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is use jquery to go through each `<a>` tag

That's the [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) function, which lets you look up elements using CSS selectors: `$("a")`

The "each" part is, amusingly, [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each):  `.each(function() { ... })`

> retrieve the title

That's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr): `.attr("title")`. But for what we're doing, we can just use the DOM's own `title` property instead.

> and then print it into a `<div class="title">titlegoeshere</div>` after each `<a>` tag is closed.

"printing" in this context is creating and adding elements to the document

- You can create an element with [a different variant of the `$()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) which accepts an HTML string: `$('<div class="title"></div>')`
- Set its text with [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text): `.text(thetitle)`
- Add it after another element with `insertAfter`

So:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $('<div class="title"><div>')
        .text(this.title)
        .insertAfter(this);
});
```

`this` in the above will be a reference to each `<a>` element that matched the opening `$("a")` search. (Not a jQuery object wrapped around it, the raw DOM element.)

More to explore in [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It's well worth taking the time to read beginning to end. Takes about an hour, maybe two, and pays you back that time immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers everyone. Sorry if I didn't present my question in a thorough enough manner.

T.J., thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

to get all the a of the page, and loop through them. Also creating a div element and appending it after the a element

```
jQuery("a").each(function (index,element){ 
 jQuery(this).after("<div class='title'>"+jQuery(this).attr("title")+"</div>");
});
```

jQuery(this) is the current a of the loop

Answer (score -1):

If you are using only native js you can use `getAttribute` to retrieve any attribute. Here is a demo

HTML

```
<a href="youtubevideo" class="fancybox" title="titlegoeshere">
    <img src="imggoeshere" />
</a>
<div class="content" id="content"></div>
```

JS

```
(function(){
var x= document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox')[0].getAttribute('title')
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=x
}())
```

if you are using jquery you can use `.attr` to retrieve

[JS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fj1o3h6r/)

**EDIT**

Initially when this question was posted it had only one anchor tag , so I used document.getElementsByClassName. But later the question was edited and multiple anchor tag got added.So document.getElementsByClassName('somName')[0] array wont work since it will only select the first element.